# Menu items have a wierd few pixels spacing between eachother

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

For some reason my menu items keep having some spacing left and right between the menu items..! While I'm kind of sure I havent programmed this..?

Anyone know why there is like 3 pixels spacing between my menu items?

http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/ceFSJ/

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
   <ul id="nav">
      <li class="page_item page-item-13">
            <a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/?page_id=13">Contact</a>
        </li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-5 current_page_item">
            <a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/">Home</a>
        </li>
      <li class="page_item page-item-7">
            <a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/?page_id=7">Nieuws</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav, #subNav {
   list-style: none;
   padding-left: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}

#nav li, #subNav li {
   display: inline;
    padding:0px;
}

/* Currently selected page nav item (and parent) if applicable */
.current_page_item a,
.current_page_parent a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:futura;;
    color:#CCC;
}

.page_item a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:futura;;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#00C;
    line-height:30px;
    width:120px;
    height:30px;
}   

#menu{
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Thanx in advance,
Greetings,
Merijn!

Comment: Didn't close your `<div>` tag properly?

Comment: Can you replicate on http://jsfiddle.net? (Just an idea, but try removing the white space between the `<ul>` and `<li>` items... have them all on one line.

Comment: <div id="topframe"><div id="menu"><?php print naked_nav($post); ?></div></div> this the line that creates my menu! its wordpress. looks fine..?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skunheal/ceFSJ/ here the jsfiddle!

Comment: @PerfectDark Thanx it indeed works. But to do this I need to modify the wordpress functions. I prefer not to since my custommer might want to use another template in the future. The 0px font for the ul solutions works. might use that since it is template based. Thanx anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set the `display` of `li`s to `inline`. So, the spaces between your `li` tags (the line-breaks and indentions) behave like spaces between words. Just remove the spaces and make it like this:

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul id="nav">
   <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/?page_id=13">Contact</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-5 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/">Home</a></li><li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/?page_id=7">Nieuws</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

You can also fix it with setting font size of `ul` to zero and setting it again on `li`s.

Comment: Thanx! I will use the font option since I dont wanna edit wordpress functions!

Comment: If setting the font-size you may also need to set the line-height to 0 to completely remove the unwanted padding.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all the white space from between the `<ul>` and `<li>` items.

Either have them in a single line, or split over the lines like this...

```
<ul id="nav"><li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/?page_id=13">Contact</a></li
><li class="page_item page-item-5 current_page_item"><a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/">Home</a></li
><li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://www.overdelijn.nl/wp/?page_id=7">Nieuws</a></li
></ul>
```

---

**Update**

Based on your JSFiddle... [here is the same fiddle with the white space removed](http://jsfiddle.net/ceFSJ/2/)